# How to prevent loading of 2 pages, when clicked for one page in angular4

Tags: html, angular

I have a profile page which comes from company page, 
here i had added data for job profile and company proposals from backend.
Here the data is getting fetched to frontend, but it loads 2 pages(i.e) profile page and company page one above the other, with an error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'recieved' of undefined
```

I am not getting where i am going wrong, please help

HTML:

```
<td  class="job">
            <thead>
              <th colspan="4">Job Requests</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="content">
              <tr>
                <td>Recieved </td>
                <td>{{jobprofiles.received}}</td>
                <td>Accepted</td>
                <td>{{jobprofiles.accepted}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Rejected</td>
                <td>{{jobprofiles.rejected}}</td>
                <td>Unanswered</td>
                <td>{{jobprofiles.unanswered}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </td>
```

TS:

```
public jobprofiles: Array<any>;
public companyprofile: Array<any>;

this.service
            .getCompanyData(id)
            .subscribe(
              data => {
                this.company = data;
                this.accepts = data.proposals;
                this.reviews = data.reviews;
                this.jobprofiles = data.jobRequests;
                this.companyprofile = data.companyProposals;
                console.log(this.jobprofiles);
                console.log(this.company);
              }, error => {})
```

Console:
This is console of company
[image]

Console of this.jobprofiles

[image]

Comment: Are you sure its about pages? Your question is a bit hard to understand. Can you post your routes, and whote ts and html files? Also, the base problem for the error message is that recieved is not found is strange, as you have no occurences of that string. (maybe received?  if yes, jobprofiles is undefined, that is your problem)

Comment: Thanks for the response, ya it is loading pages only.. and the received is also displayed on html

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using *ngIf condition in html:

HTML:

```
<tbody class="content">
              <tr>
                <td>Recieved </td>
                <td *ngIf="jobprofiles && jobprofiles.received">{{jobprofiles.received}}</td>
                <td>Accepted</td>
                <td *ngIf="jobprofiles && jobprofiles.accepted">{{jobprofiles.accepted}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Rejected</td>
                <td *ngIf="jobprofiles && jobprofiles.rejected">{{jobprofiles.rejected}}</td>
                <td>Unanswered</td>
                <td *ngIf="jobprofiles && jobprofiles.unanswered">{{jobprofiles.unanswered}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you posted was a bit misleading since it mentioned `recieved` instead of `received`

Anyway, instead of using `ngIf`, you can also use the `?` operator

```
          <tr>
            <td>Recieved </td>
            <td>{{jobprofiles?.received}}</td>
            <td>Accepted</td>
            <td>{{jobprofiles?.accepted}}</td>
          </tr>
```

Also, with the solution you posted you won't get table cell displayed if `received` or `accepted` are set to 0 (but it depends on what you want)